# JavaScript HTML DOM - Retrieve element ID outside for loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom, onclick

I need to create `checkbox` for each element in data.contents. So far I have created `checkboxes` using `createElemnt()`, set ID as their respective title and calling `myFunction()` during `onClick`. Now I am trying to retrieve ID when the checkbox is clicked using `getElementbyID(b.title)` and ended up with an error "b is not defined" which is obvious because I am trying to access b.title outside for loop.

**I can't place `myFunction()` inside for loop because `getElementById(b.title)` is giving last checkbox's ID for all `checkboxes` if i do onClick** which is also obvious because that's the last iteration's (b.title) of for loop.

My purpose is to retrieve ID(which was dynamically set inside for loop) of a `checkbox` during onClick from outside for loop. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
data.contents.forEach(b => {
  const btn = document.createElement('input')
  btn.type = 'checkbox'
  btn.setAttribute("id", b.title)
  btn.setAttribute("onClick", "myFunction();");
  var t = document.createTextNode(b.title);
  mydiv.appendChild(btn);
  mydiv.appendChild(t);
});

window.myFunction = function() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById(b.title);
  console.log(b.title)
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `setAttribute('onClick'`, consider assigning directly to the `onclick` property - that will allow you to use the `b` in that iteration *in the handler's closure*. There's also no need to create a global function, and you can simply assign to the `id` property of `btn` rather than using `setAttribute`:

```
data.contents.forEach(b => {
  const btn = document.createElement('input')
  btn.type = 'checkbox'
  btn.id = b.title;
  btn.onclick = () => {
    console.log(b.title);
    // do stuff with button and b
  };
  var t = document.createTextNode(b.title);  
  mydiv.appendChild(btn);
  mydiv.appendChild(t); 
});
```

If the only reason you were setting the ID was to be able to select it again with `getElementById` later, you can omit that entirely, due to the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
data.contents.forEach(b => {
const btn = document.createElement('input')
btn.type = 'checkbox'
btn.setAttribute("id",b.title);
btn.setAttribute("data",b.title);
btn.setAttribute("onClick","myFunction('"+b.title+"');");
var t = document.createTextNode(b.title);  
mydiv.appendChild(btn);
mydiv.appendChild(t); 
});

window.myFunction = function(id) {
var checkBox = document.getElementById(id);
console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, please explain why it does.

Comment: Okay, here we are passing argument(id) to the function and we can use this parameter inside the function.